Baidu map: southern hemisphere coordinates not working
Need to implement dynamically generated Baidu map url, the url works correctly if coordinates are for northern hemisphere, however for southern hemisphere the map won't navigate to the coordinates.
The dynamic url template:
http://api.map.baidu.com/marker?location=${lat},${long}&output=html
Not correct (Australia, Melbourne):
http://api.map.baidu.com/marker?location=-37.81434856738646,144.95672075402018&output=html
Correct (Singapore):
http://api.map.baidu.com/marker?location=1.2898402708526358,103.85528415656448&output=html
Tried to replace - with S indicator, such as:
https://api.map.baidu.com/marker?location=S37.81434856738646,E144.95672075402018&output=html

It looks like an error on baidu side.
